# Python 2.7 Django/MySQL issue

Tags: django, xampp, python-2.7

I was using Django with Python 2.7 on Windows 7 and I installed XAMPP and used the PHPMyAdmin MySQL included with it to create a database to use in Django, but when I went and used the "python manage.py syncdb" command, I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "iFriends\manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from
_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_comman
d
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 69, in load_command_
class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\syncdb.py", line 8, in <module
>
    from django.core.management.sql import custom_sql_for_model, emit_post_sync_signal
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\sql.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 92, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 24, in load_backend
    return import_module('.base', backend_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 16, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb
```

I have checked the host, username, password and those are correct, I really want to use Django so if anyone can help me on this, that would be great.

Comment: I've edited your question to format the traceback correctly. Please take a moment to understand the changes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install mysql lib for windows.

http://www.codegood.com/archives/4

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python

http://www.codegood.com/archives/129

Comment: You'll probably want to get the binary, to avoid having to build the package sources yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You require a dependency

```
easy_install mysql-python
```

Comment: It's generally recommended to use `pip` instead of `easy_install`.

Comment: Also, the above doesn't work well in Windows; where the binary package is preferred.